# mongoose subdocument array not saving the entire object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my problem I have two schemas one nested in another as an array. I am trying to push into the array and save the subdocument but it is not saving properly, I get an object that is saved but none of the fields are saved except for its _id. Do I have to save each model individually first? What is the issue here?

Here are my two schemas:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import {contactSchema} from "./ContactSchema"

export const bigSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  testField: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  contacts: [{ contactSchema }],
  }
});

export default mongoose.model("Big", bigSchema);
```

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  age: {
    type: number,
    required: false,
  }
});

export default mongoose.model("Contact", contactSchema);
```

Here is my code that I use to push to the array of contacts.

```js
 public async saveContact(
    testField: string,
    name: string,
    age: number,
  ) {
    const newContact = new Contact({
      name: name,
      age: age,
    });

    console.log(newContact);
    return UserContacts.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        testField: testField,
      },
      { $push: { contacts: newContact } },
      { new: true, upsert: true }
    );
  }
```

However when I check my database, this is what I see instead. There is an objectId but not what I expect to see, which is a list of Contact subdocuments inside my "Big" document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("XXXX"),
    "testField" : "XXXXX",
    "contacts" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("XXXXX")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: How can I make this question more clear if anyone is viewing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const bigSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  testField: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  contacts: [{ contactSchema }],
  }
});
```

should be:

```
export const bigSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  testField: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  contacts: [contactSchema],
  }
});
```

Try that and see what happens.

Edit: Also, if you intend for `contacts` to be an array of references to the `Contact` model, then you need to do this instead:

```
export const bigSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  testField: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  contacts: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Contact'}],
  }
});}
```

This will make `contacts` an array of Contact IDs, so you're not duplicating any data, but just referencing the contacts in their collection. [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: Oh god, I thought I tried that I was stuck on this for hours you are a savior!!!!!!

Comment: thank you for the updated answer as well that gives me a couple choices as to where to go with my code that I didn't know before! :D

Comment: @nuxer Yes, typically it's not good practice to store subdocuments when that same document has its own collection. Because when you duplicate data like that you now have to make sure you update the document in all places. When using a reference you only need to update the one contact in the main collection.